How to generate customized static html pages with variable number of subpages - seeking guidance, tools, direction
tl;dr, I am looking for some sort of tool or method that will allow me to generate a number of customized profiles that share a template but vary in styling, and which will also help me automate creating a variable number of subpages for each profile. Longer explanation & my current progress on the page below.
I am a completely amateur/self taught hobbyist when it comes to web development and find myself struggling to figure out where to start on certain tasks, since my foundation is very shaky. Last year, I created a website for an art event I was running for some of my friends. This website is static, but requires that each participant in the event has their own profile page, and on that profile page, they have links to 3-10 subpages.
Here is a link to my template user page, so you can get an idea of what will be customized--all the filler bits on the left sidebar, the color scheme of the sidebar, and the pages that are linked out to by the filler images. A slightly busted but customized version here so you can see what I mean.
Here is a link also to what the general format of each subpage will be like; it also contains customized portions, such as the name and bio, and a color scheme for its sidebar which matches its parent page's sidebar. It also contains a variable number of images of its own.
Due to the fact that the profiles have a large amount of customizability, I found myself having to manually create dozens of html pages and copy paste my code ad nauseum. In a fit of desperation, I eventually made a simple python script (here) that essentially asks me for the variable details, plugs them into my template, then spits out the html. However, this still requires that I manually copy paste this into my files, and manually create the up to 10 subpages, which then required a separate similar py script of their own to generate. Although these python templates sped things up, this is still painfully slow when dealing with 10-20 profiles, each with multiple subpages, and given that I expect the event to have more participants this year, it is simply no longer feasible to do this manually, and I am aware that this is a very stupid and roundabout way of achieving what I need. I know there has to be something better.
I have been overwhelmed trying to sort through the templating options I see online--either they work only for single pages and fail to address my need for creating large amounts of subpages, or they aren't customizable enough for things like variable number of links on each page, or I simply do not yet have the knowledge to be sure if they are what I need or not, and I would like to know if they will work before I dedicate my time to learning how to use them. I am very set on learning to use my own code, and not a website builder. The image hosting is not a concern, I am already planning to pay for whatever hosting I need. All I want is some sort of method, which I am sure has to exist, that allows me to have a master page where I define "This profile has X subpages, this image, this color scheme, etc" and all the html pages are created for me based on my existing html templates and the parameters I specify. I am okay with this being a static website, and generating the profiles myself--I do not expect users to be able to upload their own images. I just want it to be easier for me as the organizer to put it together. I am hosting on neocities but obviously the generating of the pages themselves can be done on my computer and I can upload the files and folders later.
Assuming this is possible, what tools would help me achieve it? I am a quick learner and I am willing to study new languages/programs to accomplish it if necessary. I just really need guidance on what I should even be working towards to accomplish this. Thank you in advance for your help, this project has gotten me in way over my head...

This question is very broad. Typically you'd have the all the user details in a database, and have a single profile file built in PHP or something that gets the user's ID from the URL, gets the users' data from the database by their ID, and populates the relevant sections on the page.

@jla My apologies for the vagueness--I just very much have no idea where to start looking as I have no classes/background in this topic at all. I will try looking into how PHP can be used for this and how I can learn how to work with a database.
